How to get manipulated table from put_datatable in pywebio
i am playing with the example code for put_datatable of pywebio
https://pywebio.readthedocs.io/en/dev/output.html#pywebio.output.put_datatable
import urllib.request
import json

with urllib.request.urlopen('https://fakerapi.it/api/v1/persons?_quantity=30') as f:
    data = json.load(f)['data']

put_datatable(
    data,
    actions=[
        ("Edit Email", lambda row_id: datatable_update('user', input("Email"), row_id, "email")),
        ("Insert a Row", lambda row_id: datatable_insert('user', data[0], row_id)),
        None,  # separator
        ("Delete", lambda row_id: datatable_remove('user', row_id)),
    ],
    onselect=lambda row_id: toast(f'Selected row: {row_id}'),
    instance_id='user'
).show()

Now i want the user to manipulate the table in the browser and afterwards i want to do something with the manipulated table. But how can i get my hands on the manipulated table?
Tried to print the manipulated table via
df= put_datatable(...)

print(df)

Or:
print(data.user())

etc. But nothing seems to work.
